# Couldn't able to connect appium inspector for android emulator in windows

Tags: android, windows, appium, appium-desktop

**Unable to connect with appium inspector for android emulator:**

```
Desire Capabilities
    {
      "platformName": "Android",
      "appium:platformVersion": "11.0",
      "appium:deviceName": "Pixel4",
      "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\prasad.sangpal\\Desktop\\ApiDemos.apk",
      "appium:appPackage": "io.appium.android.apis",
      "appium:appActivity": ".view.TextFields",
      "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2"
    }

Remote Port: 4723 | Remote Host: 0.0.0.0
Error: 
Could not connect to server; are you sure it's running? If you are using the browser version, also ensure your Appium server has been started with --allow-cors.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Appium server before starting uiautomatorviewer
2. Check your env variables and path.
3. you can open inspector using terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For **Appium server**: (I am using Appium GUI v1.22.3)

1. Open Appium Server GUI -> Click 'Advanced' tab
2. Enter the following fields as below:

   Server Address: localhost

   Server Port: 4723

   Allow CORS: Check the checkbox
3. Start the server

For **Appium Inspector**: (I am using version 2022.11.1)

1. Open Appium Inspector
2. Enter the following fields as below:

   Remote Host: localhost

   Remote Port: 4723

   Remote Path: /wd/hub
3. Expand 'Advanced Settings' and check 'Allow Unauthorized Certificates'
   checkbox
4. Select your Capability
5. Start Session